# Get MAX level per year as column value

Tags: mysql, sql, database

let's say I have the table below:

| id | user_id | level | date_created |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 2019-07-01T18:53:41.000Z |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | 2019-07-01T18:53:41.000Z |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | 2020-07-01T18:53:41.000Z |
| 3 | 1 | 4 | 2021-07-01T18:53:41.000Z |
| 4 | 2 | 2 | 2020-07-01T18:53:41.000Z |

Let's say I want to get a user's MAX/highest `level` for each of the last 3 years, based on date created, in a single row. Meaning, they can have multiple levels in a year.
So in the example above, i'd like a result like:

| user_id | 2019_level | 2020_level | 2021_level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 3 | 4 |
| 2 | null | 2 | null |

Something like:

```
SELECT user_id, MAX( IF (YEAR(CAST(`date_created` AS DATETIME)) = 2019, 
`level`,NULL)) as 'level_2019' 
,MAX( IF (YEAR(CAST(`date_created` AS DATETIME)) = 2020, `level`,NULL)) as 
'level_2020'
,MAX( IF (YEAR(CAST(`date_created` AS DATETIME)) = 2021, `level`,NULL)) as 
'level_2021'
FROM cpl_history
GROUP BY user_id
```

Isn't quite giving me what I'm wanting, obviously. I also want NULL if they do not have a level that year.

Thank you!

Comment: What is precise MySQL version? show the output for `SELECT VERSION();`. Does the datatype for `date_created` column is string?

Comment: As per provided data set the results are same http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/28f012/1 as per your desired output, I don't see any issue